# Unpickling fails with __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, pickle

When I'm trying to load a pickled list it says:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('tests/unit/support/modules_state.samples2.6') as f:
...     print(pickle.load(f))
...     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1370, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Here's the code that loads/dumps the pickled list:

```
class FakeModuleNameGenerator(str):
    def __new__(cls):
        return super(FakeModuleNameGenerator, cls).__new__(cls, binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(15)))


class FakeModule(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return choice([object(), TestDouble()])


class SamplesIterator(object):
    MAX_SAMPLE_LENGTH = os.getenv('MAX_SAMPLE_LENGTH', 12) if is_executing_under_continuous_integration_server() else 6

    def __iter__(self):
        for sample_length in range(1, SamplesIterator.MAX_SAMPLE_LENGTH):
            combinations = [(FakeModuleNameGenerator(), FakeModule()) for i in range(0, sample_length)]

            for r in range(1, sample_length + 1):
                logger.info("Generating sample in length %d with r=%d" % (sample_length, r))
                yield itertools.combinations_with_replacement(combinations, r)


def load_samples():
    if is_executing_under_continuous_integration_server() and os.getenv('USE_CACHES_SAMPLES', 'false') != 'true':
        list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(SamplesIterator()))

    import platform

    version = '%s.%s' % (
        sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1]) if platform.python_implementation() != 'PyPy' else 'pypy'
    samples_file = '%s%s' % (get_support_path(), 'modules_state.samples-%s' % version)

    if os.path.exists(samples_file) and os.path.getsize(samples_file) == 0 or not os.path.exists(samples_file):
        with open(samples_file, 'wb') as f:
            samples = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(SamplesIterator()))

            try:
                return samples
            finally:
                pickle.dump(samples, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    else:
        with open(samples_file, 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
```

As you can see I am reading and writing in binary mode.

Here is the complete tox output for the same code before loading the list (when the code is executed for the first time. After that the list is cached):

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/tox
GLOB sdist-make: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/setup.py
py26 inst-nodeps: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/dist/nose2-testsuite-0.1.0.zip
py26 runtests: commands[0]
.................................................................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 129 tests in 0.034s

OK
py27 inst-nodeps: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/dist/nose2-testsuite-0.1.0.zip
py27 runtests: commands[0]
.................................................................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 129 tests in 0.029s

OK
py33 inst-nodeps: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/dist/nose2-testsuite-0.1.0.zip
py33 runtests: commands[0]
.................................................................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 129 tests in 0.034s

OK
pypy inst-nodeps: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/dist/nose2-testsuite-0.1.0.zip
pypy runtests: commands[0]
.................................................................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 129 tests in 0.058s

OK
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
  py26: commands succeeded
  py27: commands succeeded
  py33: commands succeeded
  pypy: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

We're all happy as everything works just fine right?
Now when running tox again here are the results:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/tox
GLOB sdist-make: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/setup.py
py26 inst-nodeps: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/dist/nose2-testsuite-0.1.0.zip
py26 runtests: commands[0]
EE...........
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.functional.test_isolators (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.functional.test_isolators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py26/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 188, in _find_tests_in_file
    module = util.module_from_name(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py26/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 78, in module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/functional/test_isolators.py", line 14, in <module>
    for current_modules_state in load_samples():
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/common/support/isolators.py", line 63, in load_samples
    return pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1370, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)


======================================================================
ERROR: tests.unit.test_isolators (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.unit.test_isolators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py26/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 188, in _find_tests_in_file
    module = util.module_from_name(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py26/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 78, in module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/unit/test_isolators.py", line 48, in <module>
    for current_modules_state in load_samples():
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/common/support/isolators.py", line 63, in load_samples
    return pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1370, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=2)
ERROR: InvocationError: '/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py26/bin/nose2'
py27 inst-nodeps: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/dist/nose2-testsuite-0.1.0.zip
py27 runtests: commands[0]
EE...........
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.functional.test_isolators (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.functional.test_isolators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 188, in _find_tests_in_file
    module = util.module_from_name(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 78, in module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/functional/test_isolators.py", line 14, in <module>
    for current_modules_state in load_samples():
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/common/support/isolators.py", line 63, in load_samples
    return pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)


======================================================================
ERROR: tests.unit.test_isolators (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.unit.test_isolators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 188, in _find_tests_in_file
    module = util.module_from_name(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 78, in module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/unit/test_isolators.py", line 48, in <module>
    for current_modules_state in load_samples():
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/common/support/isolators.py", line 63, in load_samples
    return pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=2)
ERROR: InvocationError: '/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py27/bin/nose2'
py33 inst-nodeps: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/dist/nose2-testsuite-0.1.0.zip
py33 runtests: commands[0]
EE...........
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.functional.test_isolators (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/unittest/case.py", line 385, in _executeTestPart
    function()
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose2/loader.py", line 113, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.functional.test_isolators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 188, in _find_tests_in_file
    module = util.module_from_name(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 78, in module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/functional/test_isolators.py", line 14, in <module>
    for current_modules_state in load_samples():
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/common/support/isolators.py", line 63, in load_samples
    return pickle.load(f)
TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given


======================================================================
ERROR: tests.unit.test_isolators (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/unittest/case.py", line 385, in _executeTestPart
    function()
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose2/loader.py", line 113, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.unit.test_isolators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 188, in _find_tests_in_file
    module = util.module_from_name(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 78, in module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/unit/test_isolators.py", line 48, in <module>
    for current_modules_state in load_samples():
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/common/support/isolators.py", line 63, in load_samples
    return pickle.load(f)
TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=2)
ERROR: InvocationError: '/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/py33/bin/nose2'
pypy inst-nodeps: /home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/dist/nose2-testsuite-0.1.0.zip
pypy runtests: commands[0]
EE...........
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.functional.test_isolators (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.functional.test_isolators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/pypy/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 188, in _find_tests_in_file
    module = util.module_from_name(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/pypy/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 78, in module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/functional/test_isolators.py", line 14, in <module>
ERROR: InvocationError: '/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/pypy/bin/nose2'
    for current_modules_state in load_samples():
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/common/support/isolators.py", line 63, in load_samples
ERROR:   py26: commands failed
    return pickle.load(f)
ERROR:   py27: commands failed
  File "/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/pickle.py", line 1421, in load
ERROR:   py33: commands failed
    return Unpickler(file).load()
ERROR:   pypy: commands failed
  File "/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/pickle.py", line 901, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/pickle.py", line 1126, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)


======================================================================
ERROR: tests.unit.test_isolators (nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.unit.test_isolators
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/pypy/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 188, in _find_tests_in_file
    module = util.module_from_name(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/.tox/pypy/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 78, in module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/unit/test_isolators.py", line 48, in <module>
    for current_modules_state in load_samples():
  File "/home/omer/Documents/Projects/Python/nose2-testsuite/tests/common/support/isolators.py", line 63, in load_samples
    return pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/pickle.py", line 1421, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/pickle.py", line 901, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/pickle.py", line 1126, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=2)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is the error, but I just read in the docs: _Be sure to always open pickle files created with protocols >= 1 in binary mode._

Comment: We might assume that `modules_state.samples2.6` is just some random corrupted file.  You'll have to show us a code example that pickles an object correctly but fails when unpickling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it!

The problem was here:

```
class FakeModuleNameGenerator(str):
    @classmethod
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return str(binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(15)))
```

Since this inherits from str, `__new__` has to accept another argument.
Doh!